# Inventory status of configurable products is not getting updated - magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, status, stock, configurable-product

My online store is running on Magento-1.9.X

Even if all the **associated products** with respect to product become **out of stock**. the inventory status of the **configurable product** status still displays as **in stock**. And hence the product still shows up in the front end.

Can anyone kindly let me know this can be sorted out? So that one the inventory status of associated products become out of stock, the inventory status of configurable products is also updated as out of stock.